# In JS, how to sort over an object array on a value that's based on an assigned order I've created, not alphabetical or numerical?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects (objArr) which I'm sorting over multiple values for a data table. Most of the fields can be sorted alphabetically or numerically, but one of them (environment) is based on an order I created where I want them ordered by dev, then qa, then prod. I tried coming up with a way of matching each object environment to a numerical value (in environments):

```js
const environments = {
  dev: 1,
  qa: 2,
  prod: 3
};

const objArr = [
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'qa',
    version: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'prod',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'qa',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'beta project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 1
  }
]

/**
 * sort by name, then environment, then version
 */
function sortArray(items) {
    return items.sort((a, b) =>
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
        environments[a.environment].localCompare(environments[b.environment]) ||
        a.version.localeCompare(b.version)
    );
}

const newArray = sortArray(objArr);
console.log('newArray', newArray)
```

But when I run this I get an error:

"message": "Uncaught TypeError: environments[a.environment].localCompare is not a function",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 57,
"colno": 37

Apparently I can't use localCompare like this. Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Comment: You're treating the values in `environments` as though they were strings, but they're numbers. Just use `return environments[a.environment] - environments[b.environment];` in the `sort` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localeCompare`  is for strings, not numbers so you just need to subtract them.

```js
const environments = {
  dev: 1,
  qa: 2,
  prod: 3
};

const objArr = [{
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'qa',
    version: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'prod',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'qa',
    version: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'alpha project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'beta project',
    environment: 'dev',
    version: 1
  }
]

/**
 * sort by name, then environment, then version
 */
function sortArray(items) {
  return items.sort((a, b) =>
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
    environments[a.environment] - environments[b.environment] ||
    a.version - b.version
  );
}

const newArray = sortArray(objArr);
console.log('newArray', newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom sort function this way

```js
function sortArray(items) {
    return items.sort((a, b) =>{
        if(a.environment !== b.environment){ // check if environments are different
            if(a.environment === 'dev'){return 1}
            if(a.environment === 'prod'){return -1}
            if(a.environment === 'qa'){return a.environment === 'prod' ? 1 : -1}
        } else { //if they are not, just do a classic localCompare()
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
        }
    })
}
```

It should handle all cases I believe

### Edit : My solution above doesn't work

So what I would do is just splitting the original array into 3, sorting them individually, then concatenating them back in the proper order